# XSLT: numbering elements that can occur at arbitrary places in the tree

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I am struggling a bit of XSLT. My (extremely simplified) input looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <p>
        A <note>a</note>
        B <note>b</note>
    </p>
    <p>
        C <note>c</note>
        <!-- note the sneaky quote element -->
        <q>
            D <note>d</note>
        </q>
    </p>
    <p>
        E <note>e</note>
    </p>
</doc>
```

I would like to convert this to something like:

```html
<body>
    <p>
        A <span class="note-ref">1</span>
      <span class="note">
         <span class="note-num">1</span>a</span>
        B <span class="note-ref">2</span>
      <span class="note">
         <span class="note-num">2</span>b</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        C <span class="note-ref">3</span>
      <span class="note">
         <span class="note-num">3</span>c</span>
        <q>D <span class="note-ref">4</span>
         <span class="note">
            <span class="note-num">4</span>d</span>
      </q>
    </p>
    <p>
        E <span class="note-ref">5</span>
      <span class="note">
         <span class="note-num">5</span>e</span>
    </p>
</body>
```

i.e. the notes are numbered with the order they occur in the document.

The (extremely simplified) code I was using for this is as follows:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8" method="xml"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="q">
        <q>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </q>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="note">
        <xsl:variable name="num" select="count(ancestor::p/preceding-sibling::*//note) + count(preceding-sibling::note) + 1"/>
        <span class="note-ref"><xsl:value-of select="$num"/></span>
        <span class="note">
            <span class="note-num"><xsl:value-of select="$num"/></span>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That worked okay until someone rudely put a `<note>` tag *inside* a `<q>` tag, at which put the numbering was reset, because I can't figure out how to count the preceding things that might be at a different level from the focus node.

As far as I see it I need to do two things:

1. count all the notes in *preceding* paragraphs
2. count all *prior* notes in the current paragraph

Step 1 seems to work okay with `count(ancestor::p/preceding-sibling::*//note)`. Step 2 is what I can't figure out.

I'm vaguely aware that `position()` will give the count of an element within a particular selection, but I can't see how that will work in the context of my document transformation.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the `preceding` axis instead of `preceding-sibling`. Although using `xsl:number` would probably be more efficient.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks, I think that's the tip I needed. Although due to extra complications with the real data I'm going with something like `count(preceding::note[generate-id(ancestor::body[1])=generate-id(current()/ancestor::body[1])])` to limit it to those preceding in the same tree, which is probably quite slow but it seems to work!

Comment: I recommend again you explore the options provided by `xsl:number`: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template matching `note`, use `<xsl:number level="any"/>` to get the number you want.